# htaccess mod_rewrite .tld to specific folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, tld

I want to do the following, if possible, with htaccess.

The webpage works this way, you get the index file via `domain.de/de/start` and the english version via `domain.de/en/start`.

If a user visits **domain.com** I would like him to end up at `domain.de/en/` instead of `domain.de/de/` so I need to rewrite all requests to **domain.com** but NOT requests with `domain.com/xx/something` to `domain.de/en/`

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you clearly you only want to redirect `http://domain.com/` to `http://domain.de/en/` but do **NOT** want to redirect `http://domain.com/XX/YY`

Put this code in your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://domain.de/en/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `HTTP_HOST` and [`rewritecond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}=domain.de
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}=/              % redirect only the root
RewriteRule ^/$ /de/start [L]             % to /de/start

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}=domain.de
RewriteCond !%{REQUEST_URI}=/             % no root
RewriteCond !%{REQUEST_URI}=/[a-z]{2}/.*  % except /xx/ directories
RewriteRule ^/.*$ /de/$1 [L]              % push the user in the /de/ directory
```